# Permanently customize migration table in yiic migration

Tags: database-migration, command-line-interface, yii

Is there anyway to permanently force `yiic` inside `protected` folder of my application, to always (no matter, what) use customized table name for migrations?

The only way, I found is "standard" way of `yiic migrate --migrationTable=migrations`. But this is very bad approach. Any (accidental or intentional) miss / forget in adding this extra parameter and entire migration will crack, as `yiic` will create new, empty `tbl_migration` table, instead of use proper `migrations` one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MyMigrateCommand extends MigrateCommand {

    public $migrationTable='migrations';

}
```

Also you can update yiic.php file:

```
...
$app = Yii::createConsoleApplication($config);

$statConfig = require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/console.php');
$app->configure($statConfig);

$app->commandRunner->commands = $statConfig['commandMap'];
...
```

and add into config:

```
...
'commandMap' => array(
        'class'=>'system.cli.commands.MigrateCommand',
        'migrationTable'=>'stat_tbl_migration',
),
...
```

Comment: Great. But, then how to inform Yii to use my customized class, instead of base one?

Comment: ./yiic mymigrate create/up/down;
save MyMigrateCommand.php into protected/comamnds

Comment: Please clarify, on what code your answer is based? Yii 1.1.15 doesn't have [`MigrateCommand`](http://www.yiiframework.com/search/?q=MigrateCommand&lang=&type=api-suggest) class or [`migrationTable`](http://www.yiiframework.com/search/?q=migrationTable&type=api-suggest). I found `MigrateCommand` on [Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/trunk/framework/cli/commands/MigrateCommand.php) and [GitHub](https://github.com/pieterclaerhout/yii-dbmigrations). Both haven't updated for past 4-5 years. Is this part of Yii 1.x base code? Why there is nothing on this in the documentation?